# jquery dropdown menu delay

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

i made a dropdown menu for my wordpress theme.

If hovered i made it slideToggle.

The Problem is, if the mouse is moved to fast, it shows the dropdownmenu multiple times.

So i need a delay or something like this.

This is my function:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {    

        $('#menu-headermenu li > .sub-menu').parent().hover(function(){
            $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle(200);
        }); 

    });
```

Someone having a idea how i can do it better?

EDIT://

Jason's answer solved the issue.

This is my new code:

```
        $('#menu-headermenu li > .sub-menu').parent().hover(function(){
            $(this).children('.sub-menu').stop(true).slideToggle(200);
        });
```

Comment: doesn't using a larger number in **slideToggle()** work ? Like **slideToggle(1000)**.

Comment: Nope it only slow down the animation :/

Comment: What if you used `.stop()` whenever the cursor triggers the mouse out event? Have you tried using CSS transitions?

Comment: setTimeout can fix this issue.

Comment: Thank you guys. Jason .stop() solved the issue.